# Controlling another class from a different class

Tags: java, swing, panels

I am having a bit of problem regarding Swing. I have a `JFrame` called `FrameMain`. Inside it is a `JPanel` called `panelChoices`.

When `FrameMain` is called/created, it fills up the `panelChoices` object with a number of `PanelEntries` objects, which is a `JPanel` with a number of `JButton`s in it (it is a different class that I wrote).

What I want to do is when I click one of the buttons inside the `PanelEntries` object, I want to destroy/remove `FrameMain`, along with the rest of it components (including the `PanelEntries` object that contains the `JButton`).

I've tried using `super` but it returns the `JPanel` (the `PanelEntries` object) that holds the `JButton` and not `FrameMain` that holds them all together. How can I achieve this?

**EDIT**: It seems that I am not clear enough, so here's a bit more information from my work. I don't have the actual code right now because I am on a different machine but I hope this will help elaborate my question.

```
public class FrameMain() {
    private JFrame frameMain;
    private JPanel panelChoices;

    public FrameMain(args) {
        createGUI();
        loadData();
    }

    private void createGUI() {
        JFrame frameMain = new JFrame();
        JPanel panelChoices = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,1));
        frameMain.add(panel);
        // removed formatting and other design codes since they are not important.
        pack();
    }

    private void loadData() {
        boolean available;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            // do some if/else and give value to boolean available
            PanelEntries panel = new PanelEntries(i, available);
            frameMain.add(panel);
            // more code here to handle data.
        }
    }
}

public class PanelEntries() extends JPanel {

    public PanelEntries(int num, boolean avb) {
        JButton button = new JButton("Button Number " + num);
        button.setEnabled(avb);
        add(button);
        // add action listener to created button so that it calls 'nextScreen()' when clicked.
        // more code
        pack();
    }

    private void nextScreen() {
        // destroy/dispose MainFrame here.
        // See Notes.
        AnotherFrame anotherFrame = new AnotherFrame();
    }
}
```

*Notes*:

1. All classes are inside their own `.java` file.
2. I need to know *how to dispose `FrameMain` from the button inside the `PanelEntries` object*, not just disposing a JFrame.

Comment: May you provide an excerpt of your code. I think that would be more understandable than a wall of text

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to 'exit' the application.  Is this correct?

Comment: what does `super` in the `JPanel` return? Does it return the `FrameMain`? `super.dothis()` to run `dothis()` in `JPanel`. Then `super.dothat()` in `Jpanel` should give you what you need.

Comment: @fyr: I have edited the question. I hope it's clear now.

Comment: @JacoVanNiekerk No, I only need to dispose the `FrameMain` object from the `PanelEntries` object.

Comment: @abhinav: `super` (placed inside the `JButton`) returns the `PanelEntries` the button is in, and not `FrameMain`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the given information,

1. If you want to exit the application, its not a big deal use `System.exit(0);` :)
2. If you mean to dispose the frame, `jframe.dispose();`
3. If you want to remove a componet / all components you can use `.remove(Component)` / `.removeAll()` etc

If this did not help, please re-write your question with more information.